# Calling function with window scope explanation (0, function(){})()

Tags: javascript

I am curious as to why this works:

```
var c = {
    d: function myFunc() {
        console.log(this === window);   
    }
};
var a = {
    b: function() {
        console.log(this === a);
        (0,c.d)();
        c.d();
    }
};
a.b();
```

Console output:

```
True
True
False
```

So it seems to be that `(0, c.d)()` is the same as `c.d.call(window)`, but I cannot seem to find much about why or how this works. Can anyone explain?

From: [Closure Compiler Issues](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=180&q=status=Accepted&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Owner%20Summary)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wPWb4/2/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you write multiple expressions separated by a comma (`,`), then all expressions will be evaluated, but you will end up with the value of the last expression:

```
var x = (1,2,3);
console.log(x); // this will log "3"
```

Now `(0,c.d)` is an expression that will return the function `c.d`, but now `c` is not the `this` of the function anymore. This means that `this` will point to the global object (`window`), or remain undefined in strict mode. You would get the same effect with any of these:

```
var f = function(x) { return x; };
f(c.d)();
```

Or just

```
var f = c.d;
f();
```

Answer (score 16):

The expression `(0, myFunc)` is equivalent to just `myFunc`. The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator) takes multiple expressions, evaluate them, and returns the last expression, so `(0, myFunc)` returns just `myFunc`.

Now, in your `b` method, `this` is equal to `a` because `b` is attached to `a`. In other words, `b` can be called by `a.b()`. However, `myFunc` is *not* attached to `a` (you can't call `myFunc` by `a.myFunc()`), so in `myFunc`, `this` can't be `a`. In fact, `myFunc` is called without setting its `this` so it defaults to the global object `window` (or remains undefined in strict mode), and therefore its `this` is equal to `window`.

You might be wondering what the point of the `(0, listeners[i])()` is, then, when they could have just written `listeners[i]()`. Consider this code that creates an array with two elements, both functions:

```
var listeners = [
    function () { alert(this); },
    function () { alert(this); }
];
```

When you call `listeners[0]()`, then in the `listeners[0]` function, `this` is equal to `listeners`, because `0` is attached to `listeners`, just like how `b` was attached to `a`. However, when you call the function by `(0, listeners[0])()`, `listeners[0]` is "decoupled" from the `listeners` array.* Since the decoupled function no longer is attached to anything, its `this` is the global object `window`.

*It's as if you wrote:

```
var temp = listeners[0];
temp();
```