# What is a function call written as (0, fn)(argOrArgs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, waterfall

I am using Node.js async/waterfall, find this strange pattern of program:

```
var callback = (0, _once2.default)(callback || _noop2.default);
```

can someone explain what `(0, _once2.default)` means? why not directly use `_once2.default`?

Comment: you may have a look here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577812/calling-function-with-window-scope-explanation-0-function