# purpose of expression (0,foo)(x) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the libraries used in [this article](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-write-a-google-maps-react-component/) and elsewhere, and there's some pretty mind bending stuff in there, among which is the line

```
(0, _invariant2.default)(opts.hasOwnProperty('apiKey'), 'You must pass an apiKey to use GoogleApi');
```

Searching GitHub shows this piece of code, or variations on it, has been reproduced in loads of projects (although I can't find where it originated).

I can see that it boils down to a call to a function named `invariant`, but what I don't understand is the purpose of the comma operator with zero here.

Why not just write

```
_invariant2.default(opts.hasOwnProperty('apiKey'), 'You must pass an apiKey to use GoogleApi')
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577812/calling-function-with-window-scope-explanation-0-function for explanations

Comment: Which still leaves the question of "what's the point?". It's a very unreliable way of setting *this* to the global object since if run in strict mode, *this* will be undefined. It seems to pre-date strict mode though.

Comment: @RobG It's the transpiled result of [this code](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/cd4534e41c36b1d57b00b40e8a06143a07c270eb/src/lib/GoogleApi.js#L6-L7). The imported `invariant` is a function that needs to be called without a context, so to prevent `this` being set to `_invariant2` (whatever that may be), the context is stripped off.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for posting the link to the original code. I did wonder whether the code might be machine generated, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: @robertklep—I'm OK with the explanation, but not why it persists as a meme. The end result is that the value of *this* is unreliable, so clearly the called function doesn't care, so why bother even trying to set it to *global* or *undefined* because it can't matter. And if it did, then `foo.call(window, ...)` is a much better way to do it. ;-)

Comment: @RobG as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275135/why-does-babel-rewrite-imported-function-call-to-0-fn#comment65733980_32275135), `(0, foo)(...)` is shorter than `foo.call(context, ...)` ;D